# Compability Apache Tomahawk and JSF 1.2 implementation which is not MyFaces

Tags: compatibility, jsf-1.2, myfaces, tomahawk

Can you use all Apache tomahawk features if you are not using Apache MyFaces?
I found that some Tomahawk features don't work when I'm not using MyFaces. t:inputDate in particular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was javascript conflict. t:inputDate generated javasript conflicted with the js which was already present in the project

```
<script>jQuery.noConflict();</script>
```

this line solved issue